# How to get date in UK format

Tags: fullcalendar

The column dates are appearing as Sat 2/16, etc. instead of the UK format Sat 16/2. How do I change it?

```
default: 'en',
columnFormat: {                     
       day: 'dddd d/M'
},
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of FullCalendar do you have? `columnFormat` is now renamed to `columnHeaderFormat`. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderFormat. And depending where you are seeing this date, there are also other date format options for different parts of the calendar. e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeFormat, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/listDayFormat, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/listDayAltFormat, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayPopoverFormat

Comment: Of course if you want to make a general change from one country-specific style to another, the locale setting might be an easier way to do it, as per the answer below.

Comment: Lastly your date format string is incorrect. It should be `dddd D/M` - a single capital D is used for the day of the month, whereas a single small d is used for day of the week. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the locale file and then set it in your calendar config

You can read everything about it [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/localization)

> You will need to load the locale JavaScript data file in order to use it. These files are included with the FullCalendar download in the locale/ directory. They must be loaded via a  tag after the main FullCalendar library is loaded.

```
   script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale-all.js'></script> <!-- this is a file including all the locales -->
<script>

  $(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      locale: 'es'   // This is an acronym for the locale you want to select
    });

  });
```

Comment: Thanks - I have put d back to D. Sorry I had tried both and hadn't put it back to D.  Thanks it is now working  - I needed the source to the locale file adding and en changing to en-gb. The documentation wasn't very helpful